# Saving m*n array to txt file in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array of size 12*200000 as a result of some computation.
I want to save this to a .txt file.
I use the following method.
Lets just say that the array is X.

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt','w');

fprintf(fid,'%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n',x');
```

The size of the file should be around 40 MB.
It saves as a 40 MB file.But after sometime(immediately) it changes to a file of around 3 MB with some random values of the actual array. What is happening? It was working fine till a few days back. Help.

Comment: Do you actually call `fclose(fid)`?

Comment: interesting, what happens when you use `csvwrite` instead?

Comment: fid = fopen('ex.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n',x');
fclose(fid)
Error using fprintf
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Comment: When i use csvwrite,         csvwrite('ex1.txt',x)
Error using dlmwrite (line 124)
Cannot open file ex1.txt.

Error in csvwrite (line 42)
dlmwrite(filename, m, ',', r, c);

Comment: you have to write it as a csv in csvwrite, you can then view the file using any text editor - this is just to test that your file write is working (i,e, there are no funny symbols or something that is causing file write error) - you can also try to write everything as String - in case you made a mistake parsing in the wrong format